# SQL update statements updates wrong fields

Tags: postgresql

I have the following code in Postgres

```
select op.url from identity.legal_entity le
join identity.profile op on le.legal_entity_id =op.legal_entity_id     
where op.global_id = '8wyvr9wkd7kpg1n0q4klhkc4g'
```

which returns 1 row.

Then I try to update the url field  with the following:

```
update identity.profile
set url = 'htpp:sam' 
where identity.profile.url in (
select op.url from identity.legal_entity le
join identity.profile op on le.legal_entity_id =op.legal_entity_id     
where global_id = '8wyvr9wkd7kpg1n0q4klhkc4g'
);
```

But the above ends up updating more than 1 row, actually all of the rows of the identity table.

I would assume since the first postgres statement returns one row, only one row at most can be updated, but I am getting the wrong effect where all of the rows are being updated. Why ?? Please help a nubie fix the above update statement.

Comment: The best way to check is to get the value of the `op.url` from your inner query.  Then run `SELECT identity.profile WHERE identity.profile.url = 'the op.url you just got'`.  If you get more than one row, then it's your problem.

Comment: agree with Eric, identity.profile.url is probably not unique, and the way to check this is what he suggested

Comment: all rows of identity table are updated?

Comment: are you sure there isn't any end-of-line character between 'set url = 'htpp:sam'' and 'where identity.profile.url in (....' ?  you can try to assign the select value into a variable, and use it in update sentence. but it is weird that all rows are updated.

Comment: Let me be specific, identity.profile table.

Comment: can you show us the value returned by select sentence?

Comment: you are right, it is not unique at all. what could be another reason why it is updating all of the rows ?

Comment: however, legal_entity_id is unique and joins both tables .

Comment: `select op.url, le.global_id from identity.legal_entity le
join identity.profile op on le.legal_entity_id = op.legal_entity_id     
where global_id = '8wyvr9wkd7kpg1n0q4klhkc4g'`    returns the following               "say";"8wyvr9wkd7kpg1n0q4klhkc4g", 1 row only .. and I am trying to update the "say"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `profile.url` to identify the row you want to update, use the primary key. That is what it is there for.

So if the primary key column is called `id`, the statement could be modified to:

```
UPDATE identity.profile
SET ...
WHERE identity.profile.id IN (SELECT op.id FROM ...);
```

But you can do this much simpler in PostgreSQL with

```
UPDATE identity.profile op
SET url = 'htpp:sam'
FROM identity.legal_entity le
   WHERE le.legal_entity_id = op.legal_entity_id     
     AND le.global_id = '8wyvr9wkd7kpg1n0q4klhkc4g';
```